# Not able to retrieve call records from Twilio in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio

I am trying to use Twilio in my Laravel project, I have used it's aloha package. It works fine when I try to send messages or to create calls, but when I try to retrieve the call logs then it throw an exception.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    $AccountSid = <ACCOUNT ID>;
    $AuthToken = <AUTH TOKEN>;
    $client = new \Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

When I try to send message it works:

```
        try{
            $sms_content="";
            $sms_content .="Amy has requested a quote for her wedding."."\n\n";
            $sms_content .="";

            $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
                    <FROM NUMBER>, 
                    <TO NUMBER>,
                    $sms_content
                );  
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
        }
```

It also works when I try to create a call:

```
        try {
            // Initiate a new outbound call
            $call = $client->account->calls->create(
                // to call.
                <FROM NUMBER>,
                <TO NUMBER>,
                array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/")
            );
            echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

but when I try to read a call it throws an error:

```
        try {
            // Get Recent Calls
            foreach ($client->account->calls->read() as $call) {
                $time = $call->startTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                echo "Call from $call->from to $call->to at $time of length $call->duration \n";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

The error I get is:

> Call to undefined method Services_Twilio_Rest_Calls::read()

[Source](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-log#call-logs-from-rest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
$client->account->calls->read()
```

to

```
$client->account->calls
```

Comment: tried, it gives a different error: Undefined property: Services_Twilio::$calls

Comment: which version of twilio are you using

Comment: it's "aloha/twilio": "3.0.0"

Comment: the function i am trying to use is given at Twilio's official site,
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-log#call-logs-from-rest

Comment: but that is for version 4 and its $client->account->calls

Comment: it is for both laravel 4 and 5, i am using laravel 5.4

Comment: change the line to $client->account->calls, and its not version of laravel, i am talking about twilio version 4 and 5